# OpenVPN server on Raspberry Pi 2 model B limited to 5MB/s Down/Up

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, openvpn, vpn

I am running an OpenVPN server on my Raspberry Pi 2 model B and am connecting to it from my Nexus 5X. I have tested it on my cellular network (AT&T-usually 20-30 MB/s) and at my school's gigabit internet connection. When I try to do a speed test connected to my VPN server the upload and download speeds are stuck at 5MB/s. They max out at 5 and seem like it wants to go faster but is being held back. I have looked at other peoples problems with the Pi and have concluded that it is not a hardware bottleneck; I get the same limit when running the server on my desktop. I have tried solutions like disabling compression and setting sending and receiving buffers, but alas, neither have affected the speed.

Comment: Are you meaning to say MB/s?  Because 5 MB/s = 40 Mb/s, which is quite high for the Raspberry Pi 2 B.   That sounds more like a Rasp Pi 3 B.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say 5 Mb/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is a VPN connection, from the point of view of your home connection, you are *uploading* data to your VPN client.

While the RPi per se it not an extremely potent machine, at the end of the day you are more limited by your residential upstream speed than any other factor.

So at home, the speeds will be slower.

If indeed you are able to max it out at 5MB/40Mbps in a local network/gigabit connection, the figure is quite good, and if it measured in speedtest, it even means you are taking the 100Mbps ethernet to the theoretical limit of 80% of usage.

PS. I would point out that running from a speedtest normally at home, you are measuring your downstream speed; using a speedtest in a VPN client, if not constrained by CPU limits, you are measuring (roughly) your upstream speed.

Comment: I didn't by realize that my upload is the VPN speed. I get 5 Mb/s upload